# Is "this kind of way" tautology?

Tags: phrase-usage

I was talking to a friend and said:  I also prefer this kind of way.   Should it just be "I also prefer this way."?

I searched it on google, and it seems to appear only in the form of "this 'adverb' kind of way."

Comment: Hi, you should update the question with more of the dialog.  Most importantly, what was said immediately before "I also prefer this kind of way." ?   For example - "I like to roll the pizza dough like this."  What was the full topic of discussion?   This could enable a more complete answer.     Right now, it seems that *maybe* (not sure) both of your sentences could use re-wording.

Answer (score 1):

Logically it's not tautological not redundant, because kinds are nestable. You can have kinds of animals, kinds of kinds of animals, kinds of kinds of kinds of animals, ad infinitum.